# Using UITableViewCell in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm a little confused with something. I'm trying to create a custom cell and I want to use the interface builder way.

The normal way I create a table is to have the table as:

.h

```
@interface AssessList : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *tblAssessList;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tblAssessList;

@end
```

.m

```
- (NSInteger)
numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return groupArray.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return totalArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }



    cell.textLabel.text = @"I am the text....";

        return cell;
}
```

Now i've created a new class for the cell and I think I understand how to put that in. But can I leave the .h as

```
@interface AssessList : UIViewController
```

or does the class/nib with the full table on it **have** to be a UITableViewController?

Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does the class/nib with the full table on it have to be a
>   UITableViewController?

No. A `UITableViewController` is just a convenience `UIViewController` subclass which has a `UITableView` and is already setup as its delegate/datasource (it is declared as conforming to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` protocols), it also has pre-filled method implementations for these protocols in the template implementation file which Xcode generates for you. You can just as well do all of this yourself, I often do.

You should however make an IBOutlet for your UITableViewCell so that you can load it from the nib file (see the [Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW12) in the Table View Programming Guide).

Comment: Do you have to set the datasource / delegate of the UITableView nib (so the actual table) as filesowner still?

Comment: You can do it in IB (check that the fileowner class is set to AssessList) or in code (in AssessList viewDidLoad, like this: tblAssessList.delegate = self; tblAssessList.datasource = self;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do in the Interface Builder Way, then create an xib (view xib). Drag and drop a UITableViewCell object from the obj palette. Customize it as you wish. In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, do this:

```
UITableViewCell * aCell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier"];
if (aCell == nil)
{


    NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellNibName" owner:self options:nil];

    for (NSObject *anObj in arr) {

        if([anObj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {

            aCell = (UITableViewCell *)anObj;

        }
    }
}
```

The identifier for the tableviewcell can be set in the IB.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be sub class of UItableViewCell

i.e.

```
@interface AssessList : UITableViewCell
```

Comment: This is the full table, are you saying the full table should be a subclass of UITableViewCell or on the class i've created for the custom cell, that's the one that should be a sub class?

Comment: I think it was your UITavleViewCell ..... in that case it should be inherited by UITableViewController ... but still not sure

Comment: TomBeech the code line @interface AssessList : UIViewController  is perfect as it is the UIViewController sub class with table view as its subview not the file owner

Answer (score 0):

When you want a custom tableview cell you will also need a subclass of UITableViewCell..

A tutorial can be found on this [blog](http://zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/)

Keep in mind that quite a few things can be done without creating a custom cell, this includes adding the switch to make your tableview look like the one from settings.app, to the way the iPod displays songs.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have a read. What I'm trying to achieve is a picture and some text under each picture. Does that have to be in a custom class?

Answer (score 0):

In the assessList Class you are using the custom cell created in otherviewController (UITableViewCell subclass) so there is no need to change this line

@interface AssessList : UIViewController

Note:- the otherviewController should be a subclass of UITableViewCell