# UITableViewCell custom cell using IB loading data

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

From my other question; [Using UITableViewCell in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239721/using-uitablecell-in-uitableview/8239950#8239950) I've used the IB to create a custom cell. Heres how my code is at the moment:

ViewRoutes (Original Table)

```
.h

@interface ViewRoutes : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *tblRoute;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tblRoute;

@end
```

.m

```
    #import "ViewRoutes.h"
#import "ViewRoutesCell.h"

@implementation ViewRoutes
@synthesize tblRoute;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (NSInteger)
numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell * aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewRoutesCell"];
    if (aCell == nil)
    {


        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewRoutesCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (NSObject *anObj in arr) {

            if([anObj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {

                aCell = (UITableViewCell *)anObj;


            }
            return aCell;
        }
    }


}
```

and the .xib just has a UITableView on it.

The ViewRoutesCell (What I want to be the custom cell)

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewRoutesCell : UITableViewCell {

    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *routesCell;
    NSMutableArray *arryRouteText;
    NSMutableArray *arryRouteImage;

    IBOutlet UILabel *lblRouteText;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblRouteImage;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arryRouteText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arryRouteImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *lblRouteText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *lblRouteImage;

@end
```

The only thing i've done in the custom cell .m is synthesized the items

Then my custom cell xib i've got:

[image]

[image]

[image]

From here I get a little stuck, I can't work out how to set the two label properties from my ViewRoutes.m (they will be coming from xml eventually, but for now just a mutablearray)

Am I doing this the right way?

Tom

**Edit** Just to let you know i'm loading the image string to a label for now, will be an image later

Comment: What is it that you want to do exactly? Are you trying to edit the label properties for your custom cell or are you trying to edit properties of the ViewRoutes.m file?

Comment: I'm trying to edit the lables properties for the custom cell from the ViewRoutes.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the declaration of

```
UITableViewCell * aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewRoutesCell"];
```

you're creating a `UITableViewCell` object. This does not know about your custom defined labels. You should change it to:

```
ViewRoutesCell * aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewRoutesCell"];
```

Then, in the `if` clause, you should change

```
aCell = (UITableViewCell *)anObj;
```

to

```
aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)anObj;
```

This will make the compiler recognize the object as being one of your specific cells, allowing you to access the label properties.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much for this! We're so close. Just one more question, how do I make the cells take the design for my custom cell nib I've created? http://screencast.com/t/TIw0WFbTxd for example is how it's coming up

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing this... Try this: in the isKindOfClass call, write ViewRoutesCell instead of UITableViewCell. If that doesn't solve it and you can't figure it out, check out this tutorial: http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/. It has everything you'll need in great detail. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As you have define property for UILabel, you must have **@synthesized** in **ViewRoutesCell.m** file.

Now, its easy to access properties of those labels.

In your **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, modify following part of code.

```
for (NSObject *anObj in arr) {
    if([anObj isKindOfClass:[ViewRoutesCell class]]) {
        aCell = (UITableViewCell *)anObj;
        aCell.lblRouteText.text = @"My Route Text"; 
        aCell.lblRouteImage.text = @"My Route Image";
     }
     return aCell;
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but it's not exposing the properties to let me access lblRouteText or lblRouteImage. I have the .h loaded in my ViewRoutes.m and the properties synthesized in my ViewRoutesCell.m

Comment: Property 'lblRouteText' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: That's because you shouldn't cast anObj to UITableViewCell *, but to ViewRoutesCell *.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of for loop
replace your for loop by following code

```
acell.lblRouteText.text = [arryRouteText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
acell.lblRouteImage.text = [arryRouteImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return acell;
```

As you have put the return statement in For loop , it will always use the first object , and rest of the objects will never get a chance to get assigned.

And , you can not assign image to label , for that you will have to use UIImageView.

Comment: Thanks for that, as above though it doesnt let me do aCell.lblRouteImage or aCell.lblRouteText as if they've not been exposed, but I'm sure they should be

Comment: Property 'lblRouteText' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: It seems  you have not synthesized properly.

Answer (score 0):

you should set ViewRoutesCell class to the IB cell as file's owner, and then you can link these property to IB file

Comment: or   - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        _goodsImgView = (UIImageView *)[self subviewWithTag:1];
        _eventImgView = (UIImageView *)[self subviewWithTag:2];