# UITableCell Custom Cell not taking height of custom cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

A follow on to my last question [UITableViewCell custom cell using IB loading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241236/uitableviewcell-custom-cell-using-ib-loading-data/8241879#8241879) probably best to start a new one for a new question!

My Custom cell is loading (designed in IB)

Here is my xib file for the custom cell:

[image]

And heres how it loads in my table:

[image]

So it's not loading the size properties for the custom cell (but it's loading the text to the right labels and it's loading the blue arrow on the right from the nib)

Heres how the code is populating the table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    ViewRoutesCell * aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewRoutesCell"];

    if (aCell == nil)
    {


        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewRoutesCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (NSObject *anObj in arr) {

            if([anObj isKindOfClass:[ViewRoutesCell class]]) {
                aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)anObj;
                aCell.lblRouteText.text = [arryRouteText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                aCell.lblRouteImage.text = [arryRouteImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }



        }
}

    return aCell;
}
```

What am I doing wrong loading the cell?

Tom

Comment: just set rowHeight property of your tableview 
`[self.tableView setRowHeight:30];` or whatever your height should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` You may need this method(UITableView's delegate method).
Just return the height you want. Or judge for different type of cell by `indexPath`.

Comment: Can it not just inherit it from the xib file?

Comment: @TomBeech, Yes it can. Generally speaking, you can set the `row height` in your Interface Builder(`Inspector`->`Table View Size`->`Row Height`). Maybe it's the `Group` tableView's problem or you miss something. Why not have a try? ;)