# table view custom cell trouble

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view. I use a custom cell to view pictures in it. I've set all the delegate and data source methods and made connection to the custom cell. Everything should work fine... But my table view looks like this:

[image: the way my table view looks]

It divided the cell into two parts and photo as well. And I've set the height of my custom cell higher than it shows. Can anyone help me? I can provide the code, if needed. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the cell height by `setCellHeight` or `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`(just return the cell height you want)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243376/uitablecell-custom-cell-not-taking-height-of-custom-cell/8243419#8243419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple suggestions:

1. Make sure that, when you set the custom cell's height you set it like this: `customCell.contentView.frame = ...`, not `customCell.frame = ...`.
2. In the delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, calculate your cell and set the height as `return cell.contentView.frame`.